# How to modify part of a list of floats?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list named lon_list that contains a number of float values ranging from 0 to 360. I am interested in subtracting 360 from any floats greater or equal to 180 in the list. How would I do this?

Here is my current attempt:

```
for x in lon_list:
   if x>=180:
      x-360
lon_list
```

Comment: Can you use NumPy?

Comment: Your problem is that you are iterating on the elements and when trying to change, you simply change the local variable. To change the contents of the list, iterate on the indices using `range` and then change as `lst[i] = lst[i] - 360`. Assuming the line `x-360` is a typo? as it does nothing... maybe you meant `x = x-360`

Comment: Use a list comprehension otherwise with a ternary if: `lon_list = [x-360 if x>= 180 else x for x in lon_list]`.

Comment: I have added an answer. Hope it helps

Comment: I also suppose you need a modulo function if x > 360 ?

Comment: @GOVINDDIXIT it is not necessary to comment about adding an answer. We can see it and the OP even gets a notification for it!

Comment: Got it. Thanks @Tomerikoo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
lon_list = [12, 13.50, 183.54, 205.80]
lon_list = [x-360 if x>= 180 else x for x in lon_list]
print(lon_list)
```

**Output**

```
[12, 13.5, -176.46, -154.2]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use a list comprehension to create a new list with the required changes:

```
lon_lis = [x if x < 180 else x - 360 for x in lon_lis]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to use `numpy`, you can use `enumerate`

```
for index, val in enumerate(lon_list):
    if val >= 180.0:
        lon_list[index] -= 360.0
```

If you can use `numpy`, you could do something like `lon_list[lon_list >= 180.0] -= 360.0`

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the list in place:

```
for i in range(len(lon_list))
    if lon_list[i] >= 180:
        lon_list[i] -= 360
```

A List comprehension solution is faster than modifying the list in place. But modifying the list in place may be necessary if there are other references to the list. Here is a simple benchmark with approximately 82% of the list elements needed to be updated, which favors the list comprehension solution.

```
from random import uniform
from time import time

the_list = [uniform(1.0, 1000.0) for i in range(1000)]

N_TRIALS = 10000

def test_1():
    t1 = time()
    for trial in range(N_TRIALS):
        lon_list = the_list[0:]
        for i in range(len(lon_list)):
            if lon_list[i] >= 180:
                lon_list[i] -= 360
    t2 = time()
    print("running time for test_1:", t2 - t1)



def test_2():
    t1 = time()
    for trial in range(N_TRIALS):
        lon_list = the_list[0:]
        lon_list = [x if x < 180 else x - 360 for x in lon_list]
    t2 = time()
    print("running time for test_2:", t2 - t1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_1()
    test_2()
```

running time for test_1: 1.3320763111114502

running time for test_2: 0.8780503273010254

When the above benchmark is modified so that only 10% of the elements need to be modified, we get:

running time for test_1: 0.7290420532226562

running time for test_2: 0.603034257888794

And when none of the elements need to be modified:

running time for test_1: 0.6360366344451904

running time for test_2: 0.5660324096679688

Comment: Why are list comprehensions expensive (compared to a plain loop)?

Comment: In fact, list comprehensions are generally _faster_ than an equivalent, explicit loop

Comment: You are creating a whole new list which requires allocating memory, copying unmodified elements over, etc. What if the list had no elements >-= 180. All of that allocation and copying would have been more work compared with the above solution which would have simply examined each element in place and updated nothing.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez Perhaps. But what if it was important to modify the original list in place because there were references to it?

Comment: You should add those reasons in your answer, not in comments.

Comment: Each case is different, of course. But without more context, nowadays the preferred approach is to use list comprehensions. Memory is cheap, and mutating data structures in-place, although efficient, can introduce errors. Prefer a functional-ish style of programming when writing Python code.

Answer (score 0):

Many modern languages support map, filter, and reduce functions. This approach would feel more familiar and can be used in other languages.

```
recalculated = map(lambda x: x-360 if (x >= 180) else x, lon_list)
```

`map(function, iterable)` remaps all values in the iterable (like lists and tuples) to a new collection based on the provided function.

The function in this case, takes one argument and returns a result.

The `lambda x: ...` is an anonymous function. Basically the function is declared in the expression.

If you wanted to, you could declare the function separately and use it in the `map`.

```
def calc(x):
    return x-360 if (x >= 180) else x

recalculated = map(calc, lon_list)
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map

Comment: What is vanilla Python? What does it not have that other solutions here show?

Comment: Saw a solution that suggested using numpy. Vanilla just means python and its standard libraries.

Comment: As for what makes this solution different, it works around immutable data - i.e. tuples in python.

Comment: I don't see a solution that uses NumPy; there's only a comment asking about NumPy. You should point out in your answer, not in a comment, about immutable tuples (which is also avoided by the list comprehension).

Comment: @00 I've updated my answer. I suppose my reasoning will pivot to applicability with other languages :)